# xdg-open command in terminal

Tags: command-line, ssl, https, xdg-open

when i use xdg-open with http it works fine

But when i try opening it with https it says this

```
Secure Connection Failed
```

An error occurred during a connection to 10.0.2.15:22533. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

```
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

Learn more…

Comment: Which Ubuntu version and browser are you using?

Comment: 19.0 version of ubuntu

Comment: There's no 19.0 release of Ubuntu. Did you mean 19.04 or 19.10? And what about the browser?

Comment: i am using chrome with  19.10